# Converting specific Node in XSD to upper case

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

can you please help me with the following problem.
I need to convert the value(name) of the fields

```
simpleType & element in upper case.
```

I just need the Name of the specific Fields in upperCase.

This is my input XSD

> 

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xsd:simpleType name="ID">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Datatype string Length 18</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="18"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="AccountId">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Datatype string Length 18</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="18"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="AssignedToQueueDateTime_c">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Datatype string Length 28</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="28"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:element name="dataTable">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="dataRow" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="ID" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ID"/>
                            <xsd:element name="AccountId" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="AccountId"/>
                            <xsd:element name="AssignedToQueueDateTime_c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="AssignedToQueueDateTime_c"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

The Output XSD should be :

> 

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xsd:simpleType name="ID">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Datatype string Length 18</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="18"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="ACCOUNTID">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Datatype string Length 18</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="18"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="ASSIGNEDTOQUEUEDATETIME_C">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Datatype string Length 28</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="28"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:element name="dataTable">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="dataRow" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="ID" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ID"/>
                            <xsd:element name="ACCOUNTID" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ACCOUNTID"/>
                            <xsd:element name="ASSIGNEDTOQUEUEDATETIME_C" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ASSIGNEDTOQUEUEDATETIME_C"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Do you have a  XSLT Mapping for me ?
I would be very thankful!

lowercase to uppercase for specific field in XSD

**EDIT**

This is what i tried.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:variable name="smallCase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="upperCase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()[not(@lang)]/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $smallCase, $upperCase)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thank you for your comment.
I tried XSLT, but didnt get the XML Node's to UpperCase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="smallCase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
<xsl:variable name="upperCase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xsd:simpleType/@name | xsd:element/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $smallCase, $upperCase)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```